# How can I prevent my phone from vibrating when service is lost or re-acquired?

Tags: cyanogenmod, notifications, nexus-4, vibration

I find it annoying when I'm in an area with poor service, that my phone vibrates every 15 seconds to tell me that service has been lost, or re-aquired.  How can I disable this vibration?

I have a Nexus 4 with CyanogenMod 10.1.0 (Android 4.2.2).

**EDIT:** As noted in the (so far) only answer, I can disable all vibrations.  I may resort to this, but this is not really what I'm looking for. I'd like to continue with vibrations for other notifications, if possible.

Comment: I don't get this at all. Have you tried disabling haptic feedback?

Comment: @LiamW: I have not, but that doesn't seem related. That's an input pref, from what I can tell.  The notifications I want to change have nothing to do with input. I'd love to be wrong, though, if you want to provide an answer along those lines...

Comment: This might be a specific case to CyanogenMod since I didn't experience this on Nexus 4 with stock ROM.

Answer (score 1):

Check under settings > sound, there will be an option of vibrate on notification turn that off may be this is the possible solution.

Comment: That may be what I have to do.  I'd rather only disable service lost/found vibrations, and continue to receive other notification vibrations if possible.

Comment: have you any other app that gives you some security features accessing your cell radio?